# Koajs and curl with Content-Encoding: gzip,deflate

Tags: node.js, http, curl, gzip, koa

I am looking for simple example of exchange data between client (using curl) and Koajs server with Content-Encoding: gzip,deflate.

More detail: the client have log file. Client compress the log file and send the log file to server. Server decompress the log file and get the content.

Please give me both curl command and Koajs code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you wanna send compressed request to server using curl you can do so using

`curl -v -H "Content-encoding: gzip" -X POST -H 'Content-Type:
application/json;charset=UTF-8' --data-binary @youdataFile.gzip
your_endpoint.com`

and if you wanna decompress that request in koaServer, I don't really know about that but would surely like to know. As even I'm in need to know that

Comment: hey @Point Networks,  I post how to decompress data using zlib. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you @HahaTTpro for the solution, although I haven't yet tried it but will surely give it a try

Answer (score 0):

This is how I decompress data in Koa Server using [zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html)

```
var zlib = require('zlib');

zlib.unzip(buffer, (err, buffer) => {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    var dataString = buffer.toString();
});
```